# How to use ChartOptions in vue-chartjs with Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-chartjs

I am trying to use vue-chartjs but implement it with composition api. Most examples are either in typescript which I am not familiar with or using options api. I am unable to get chartOptions to work. I am not sure if I should be removing the chart-options and just do options or if there is something else I am missing such as an import. I tried to import ChartOptions in the chart-js import statement but it draws an error. Any help on how to implement this would be very helpful. Thanks!

```
<template>
  <Pie
    :chart-options="chartOptions"
    :chart-data="chartData"
    :chart-id="chartId"
    :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
    :plugins="plugins"
    :css-classes="cssClasses"
    :styles="styles"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
  />
</template>

<script>
import {ref, defineComponent, onMounted} from 'vue'
import {Pie} from 'vue-chartjs'
import {Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale} from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale)

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'SectorPieChart',
  components: { Pie },
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      default: 'pie-chart'
    },
    datasetIdKey: {
      type: String,
      default: 'label'
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      default: 500
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 500
    },
    cssClasses: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    },
    styles: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    },
    plugins: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  setup() {
    //stores
    const portfolioStore = usePortfolioStore()
    const {portfolio} = storeToRefs(portfolioStore)

    //dataset
    const chartData = ref({
        labels: [ 'Basic Materials', 'Consumer Cyclical', 'Financial Services', 'Real Estate', 'Consumer Defensive', 'Healthcare', 'Utilities', 'Communication Services', 'Energy', 'Industrials', 'Technology'],
        datasets: [
          { 
            backgroundColor: ['#FF4A4A','#FFAC4A','#FFE9C9','#F9C87C','#F97432','#7a7979','#FFCC00','#FF9900','#86370e','#FFFF66','#ed9e67'],
            data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
          },
          { 
            backgroundColor: ['#FF4A4A','#FFAC4A','#FFE9C9','#F9C87C','#F97432','#7a7979','#FFCC00','#FF9900','#86370e','#FFFF66','#ed9e67'],
            data: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
          }
        ]
    })

    //chart options to change settings
    const chartOptions = ref({
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        }
      })

    //methods
    const loadData = () => {

    }
      
    //add on mount API request
    onMounted(() => {
      loadData()   
    })

    return {
      chartData, chartOptions, loadData
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: you say you're getting an error.  what's the error?

Comment: @yoduh it only draws an error if I add ChartOptions to the import statement and says "SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'ChartOptions' is not found." Otherwise there is no error and it just does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the vue-chartjs there is no `ChartOptions` object/function that you can import.  You're just meant to create your own array of options and bind it to the `:chart-options` prop, exactly how you're doing already.

In order to properly set chart options you should follow the [chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html). As the documentation there notes, the legend options are namespaced as `options.plugins.legend`, and includes boolean property `display` that can turn off the legend display.  This means we should format our chart options like so:

```js
const chartOptions = ref({
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
});
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-http-vleigt?file=/src/App.vue:1132-1240) here.

Comment: I checked your sandbox and the legend is still showing despite it’s listed as false. So how do you mean it’s still working?

Comment: oh, I completely misunderstood your issue.  I thought you were having trouble generating the actual chart.  you're just having trouble setting certain options... I see now.  I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Make computed your chartOptions:

```
const chartOptions = computed(() => {
  return ({
   maintainAspectRatio: true,
   plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
   },
  },
 })
})
```

And that's it...